# How to say "any [type of data]" in angular Jasmine unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'd like to write a test that looks something like this:

```
expect(myService.myMethod()).toEqual({
      theDate: any Date,
      title: 'My Title',
...
    });
```

Is there a way in Jasmine to expect against type? So: any string, any number, any Date, etc? Is that legal, or a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jasmine.any(Class)` to match against any type.

i.e.,

```
expect(new Date())
  .toEqual(jasmine.any(Date));
```

See https://jasmine.github.io/api/4.4/jasmine.html for more info.